# I'm trying to setup custom nameservers but this does not make sense - At all

Tags: bind, domain-name, nameserver, resolve

I have a VPS running WebHost Manager and my boss wants to run custom nameservers so the sites we then setup use 'ns1.ourbusiness.com' rather than something like 'ns1.xname.org'.

Here's the steps I assume need to be taken:

- Buy a domain name
- Login to the domain name control panel and set up it's nameservers
- Point the nameserves to my VPS running Bind

Now, practically every tutorial I read on this says to use 'ns1.ourbusiness.com' rather than an IP address. But, how on earth do I do that? 'ns1.ourbusiness.com' can't resolve to anything until I setup the ourbusiness.com domain name and point the ns1 subdomain to our VPS... It's like a 'which came first - chicken or the egg' situation :/

So to summarise my question:
How can I create a custom nameserver on my VPS, via WebHost Manager, and use that as the resolver for all the future domain names I purchase?

Answer (score 3):

Once you get you bind name servers up, you'll have to create what are known as "GLUE" records with your registrar. These records - simply -  allow the root name servers to look up the IP of your DNS servers.

The procedure is different for each registrar, but their tech support should be able to point you in the right direction if it's not obvious (i think netsol has an add new Name Server link for example)

[Further Reading on the issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)

Comment: If this is your first time setting up a DNS server I strongly suggest buying and reading the O'Rielly Cricket Book ("DNS and BIND") before you try to make this happen.